# Remove a content from the yimg

Tags: url, upload, yahoo-mail

My CV is uploaded on a website called `Yimg` without prior permission and I have no idea how this happened. The URL is like this:

`https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/3434348397/1898894793/name/fileName.pdf`

It seems the Yahoo owns this domain and further proof that Yahoo owns this domain by the website’s favicon. It’s Yahoo’s logo. When I was researching about this website, several users on forums say that Yimg is a Yahoo tracking “thingy”.

Understandably, the Google can't remove the content till the website owner has removed it. How do I contact the site owner and request a removal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yimg.com` is Yahoo's CDN service – it hosts any kind of static files that are part of their website, such as images, stylesheets, webfonts, or user uploads. Different subdomains have different purposes, but in general it's used for data storage.

In this case, `https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/` hosts files uploaded by Yahoo Groups users. (These used to act as mailing lists, and now work similar to Facebook groups – each group's members can post messages, upload photos and files.)

In short, it's user-contributed content. If you want Yahoo to remove it, you'll probably need to send a [copyright infringement report](https://policies.oath.com/us/en/oath/ip/index.html) to their owners (Oath Inc.).

Comment: I sent an email to them and see what's happen

Comment: I sent an email to the address `copyright@yahoo-inc.com` 2 days ago and no reply so far. My email address, DoB, and phone number are online and I'm little worried by now. I will give it a week and then, call them to check.